# Generic parameter extending a literal type, is different from the literal type itself?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the following [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQUwHgDg9gTgLsOBPCJgGEAWUCWBjEAFRTQF5gBvYAaxwDsATALmAHIBnHAWwgBsRWwAL7AAPgChgU6TNlz5lGvWZs8UHvzCsA3KDBwYAQxZ0ArlwBGIGMO2Tp4gGam6eODih1gAMRd4AjAA8hHpwIIzsqup84KwAfAAUhjAA5iwAovpGboFYuATEqAA0irSMLCFCcQCUlPZSanTsCKbA5MkpAHTgBoa6APT9wOkwMLAsEGOo8EhsPUaCDFAgkXRQCOA4zZ074kJOfu6ePn4ATEmpGVmGOXn4RCQlVGUqrGoasVW1FPXAjc3AVrtVLda4DIYAOSgoFGsD2QA), `extra` is not found, unless the generic type `T` (that `extends 'complex'`) is replaced by `'complex'`.

```
export type ChoiceType = { kind: 'simple' } |
                         { kind: 'complex'; extra: number };

function Func1<T extends 'complex'>(arg: Extract<ChoiceType, { kind: T }>) {
    const u = arg.extra; // Error: property 'extra' does not exist...
}
function Func2(arg: Extract<ChoiceType, { kind: 'complex'}>) {
    const u = arg.extra; // No error
}
```

I don't understand why Typescript cannot see `extra` in the first case. Maybe somebody can help?

Comment: What’s the type of `arg` in your case?

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine The type as in `Func1`. If there is another way to access `extra`, without error, that would also be nice.

Comment: Not what I was asking about, but it’s fine. The type of `arg` is `Extract<{ kind: "simple" }, { kind: T }> | Extract<{ kind: "complex", extra: number }, { kind: T }>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Extract` is implemented as a *conditional type*.

```
type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never
```

Passing a *generic* type `T` to `Extract` is a tricky situation for the compiler. It is not yet known what the type of `T` is. The *caller* of the function determines the type of `T`.

To know what the shape of `arg` is, the compiler has to find out if  `ChoiceType` extends `{ kind: T }`. But without knowing the type of `T`, the compiler *defers* evaluation of the conditional. The type of `arg` remains essentially *opaque*. A mostly unanalyzed type of unknown shape.

Now we are dealing with a kind of edge case here. You have set the constraint of `T` in a way that does only allow one valid type, the string literal `'complex'`. Knowing this, the conditional can only ever evaluate to the *true* branch. But the compiler does not use the *constraint* of a generic type  to do this kind of analysis. It just sees the generic type and stops reasoning about the result of the conditional until the type of `T` is known.